# Compilation error: x86_64-linux-gnu missing

Tags: boost, compilation, ubuntu-12.04, x86-64, gnu

After upgrading boost to 1.55 version, I had the titled issue. The problem is that when trying to compile c++ codes I get error messages like

```
*** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib*.so'
```

It seems that all libraries related to x86_64-linux-gnu have been deleted.
Please, any idea to fix correctly this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved after:

```
sudo apt-get install lib*-dev
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

Comment: That's enormous overkill. The former command installs pretty much every library in the Debian repository.